# How to speed up Gitlab CI build of a c/c++ project with caching

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am building a C/C++ project in the Gitlab CI. Its compilation result is 360 `.lo` files and the binary (executable) file. It's a slow process, so I want to speed up it. I thought about caching. How to do it? Before, I used caching for npm, Python modules/packages. But now it's C/C++ object files and they are 360 items. How to do it with CI Yaml file? All these object `.lo` files are located together with source files in the `src/` directory.

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following:

1. Use [Ccache](https://ccache.dev/)
2. Use the Gitlab cache to cache the Ccache cache folder.

```
variables:
  CCACHE_BASEDIR: $CI_PROJECT_DIR
  CCACHE_DIR: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ccache
before_script:
  - ccache --zero-stats
script:
  - build your files here
after_script:
  - ccache --show-stats
cache:
  - key: ccache-$CI_JOB_NAME
      paths:
        - $CCACHE_DIR
```

Here is an [example .gitlab-ci.yml file](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/blob/23b485c920a64ba302a908e7b13c89bc7a76565e/.gitlab-ci.yml) using it, and [the MR diff](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/merge_requests/240/diffs) where the functionality was added.

Answer (score 1):

Caching is the same no matter what objects you're using, so the syntax will be the same for npm and python. In the job that builds your .lo files, add the cache information following the suggestions in the docs (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/). Then for any other pipelines for that branch (or however you set it up) jobs that depend on the .lo files will download them from the cache instead of creating them.

Comment: is it possible to specify glob expression in `files:` directive of the `cache:`? Or to specify the whole directory `src/` together with source (.c, ,cpp) files?

Comment: You can cache entire directories, or single files. The example here (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#inherit-global-configuration-but-override-specific-settings-per-job) shows caching directories like `node_modules` from an `npm install` operation.